# Oracle Datapump between different database releases

Tags: oracle, datapump

I need to transfer schemas from an Oracle 12.1.0.2 Database to an Oracle 11.2 XE Database. According to

[Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-BAA3B679-A758-4D55-9820-432D9EB83C68.htm#SUTIL110):

> On a Data Pump export, if you specify a database version that is older
> than the current database version, then a dump file set is created
> that you can import into that older version of the database. For
> example, if you are running Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2)
> and specify VERSION=11.2 on an export, then the dump file set that is
> created can be imported into an Oracle 11.2 database...

I used the following `expdp` command:

```
expdp system/XXXX 
    directory=name 
    dumpfile=dump_24.8.2018.dp 
    consistent=y 
    version=11.2 
    logfile=dump_24.8.2018.log 
    schemas=name1,name2
```

The impdp fails with errors that the dump has version 12.

> `<ERROR DETAILS>`

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: could you please post the exact error message?

Comment: Is requested from the customer. Request is pending. I will post it as soon as I have it.

Comment: maybe the dump has types of objects that don't exist in 11.2? If you tried expdp from your 11.2 home it might flag these as objects it cannot export.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use the version 12 impdp to import into the Oracle 11.2 XE Database.

Comment: According to Oracle docs we only have to use Version=12 for database link impdp, right?

Comment: I don't understand your question, and I have to admit that I found Oracle docs in this regard rather confusing.